# Adding attributes with hook_node_view_alter

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to modify the "Add new comment" link in certain nodes, and for this I'm using hook_node_view_alter like this:

```
function example_node_view_alter(&$build) {
//    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['attributes']['class'] = 'nice small radius blue button';
      $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title'] = t('Add a review');
}
```

The commented line is causing trouble though,... since the array doesn't have a 'class' attribute. If I just add it to the array like that, every time I clic on the "add a review" link, the website isn't rendered properly... so how can I add it without ruining everyhting else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` property is an array so you need to initialise it like this:

```
$build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['attributes']['class'] = array(
  'nice',
  'small',
  'radius', 
  'blue',
  'button'
);
```

Comment: As far I understood attributes starts from #. ['#attributes'].

Comment: Oddly enough that doesn't work (I tried it). The above Is the only way I could find to override the classes